# Batch file to delete shortcuts from desktops

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have a lab with 30 Windows 7 computers. I would like run a batch file that sends a command to each of these computers that would delete a specified shortcut from the Public\Desktop. This is what I have so far:

`del "\\875L-I2-196208T\c$\users\public\desktop\Neighborhood MapMachine.lnk"`

When I run this, I get an error stating it can't find the file.

Comment: Are you running the batch/command from a command prompt opened "As Administrator"?  If you perform a `dir "\\875L-I2-196208T\c$\users\public\desktop\"`, is the link you're looking to delete listed?  Do you get a response if you ping 875L-I2-196208T?

Comment: How are you invoking the batch file (scheduled task, running from Explorer, etc.)?  Does this command work from a regular command line outside of the batch file?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge you are not allowed to use spaces in file names within a batch script. This is because it is going to consider the text after the space as a new argument, which is where quotes come in. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805799/how-to-get-a-batch-file-to-handle-spaces-in-file-names) on stack overflow might help with the formatting for this.

So, to test this, I created a file called "test 2" on my desktop. To erase the file, I ran the following command in cmd:

```
del "C:\Users\Daedalus\Desktop\Test 2.txt"
```

I did not need to use the $ symbol.

Comment: 1) The OP has quotes around the path in the example in their question, so they're already doing what you suggest. 2) OP wants to run it on multiple, remote computers, hence why he's trying to use an UNC path and the admin shared (c$). :)

Comment: Admittedly I'm much more familiar with bash, but the command I used was virtually identical.  My guess would be that there is either a typo (notorious in command prompts) or he should attempt removing the $

Comment: while I don't disagree that the OP should triple-check spelling. :) The use of C$ is completely normal for accessing Windows drives in an UNC path.  His command syntax, as written, should work.

Comment: @Daedalus `c$` is the share name for the default share associated with resource "C:\"